# How to disable "Flash while ringing" on the Xiaomi A2 Lite

Tags: calls, accessibility, flashlight, xiaomi-mi-a2-lite

My Xiaomi A2 Lite flashlight illuminates whenever I get a phone call. How can I disable this feature?

I tried looking at Settings > Apps & Notification > Phone > Phone > App notification > Incoming calls. Unfortunately there is no "Flash while ringing" option there.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Go to Settings.
2. Tap on System Apps.
3. Tap on Phone Section.
4. Choose Incoming Call Settings.
5. Now disable “Flash when ringing” option.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open Phone App → click the three horizontal bars in the bottom left corner → Settings.

Alternatively, go to *Settings → App Settings Section → System Apps → Call settings*. You should now be in call settings. Now go to *Incoming calls settings → Flash while ringing*.

If you require pictures, you can follow the introduction and #3 in the [10 Best Xiaomi Redmi Devices Call Settings Tips & Tricks](https://www.guidingtech.com/xiaomi-redmi-call-settings-tips-tricks/) article.